# Rails 4: run migrations as separate DB user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, privileges, rails-migrations

The situation I have is our normal Rails DB user has full ownership in order to run migrations.

However, we use a shared DB for development, so we can't run "destructive" DB tasks against the development DB, such as `rake db:drop/reset/etc...`.

My thought is to create 2 DB users:

- rails-service
- rails-migrator

The service user is the "normal" web app user that connects to the DB when the app is live. This DB user would only have standard CRUD privileges but no dropping rights.

The migrator user is the "admin" user that is only used for running migrations. This DB user would have normal "full" access to the DB such that it "could" drop the DB if that command were executed.

**Question:** Is there a clean way to tell Rails migrations to run as the `rails-migrator` user?  I'm not sure how I would accomplish this aside from somehow altering the connection strings for every rails migration file, which seems like a bad idea.

In tandem with the above, I'm going to "delete" the destructive rake tasks so that a developer can't even run them.

```
# lib/tasks/db.rake
# See: https://coderwall.com/p/jt4e1q/disable-destructive-rake-tasks-by-environment
tasks = Rake.application.instance_variable_get '@tasks'
tasks.delete 'db:reset'
tasks.delete 'db:drop'
namespace :db do
  desc 'db:reset not available in this environment'
  task :reset do
    puts 'db:reset has been disabled'
  end
  desc 'db:drop not available in this environment'
  task :drop do
    puts 'db:drop has been disabled'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to the answer of Matthew Rudy Jacobs from 2007 (!) https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/123618
Lucky enough it works also now :)

I just changed `DEFINED?` and the rest to `ENV['AS_DB_ADMIN']` and used it to separate migration access to another user.

On migration I used 
`set :default_env, { as_db_admin: true }`